# php imagick convert PNG to jpg

Tags: php, png, jpeg, imagick

```
$image = "[...]"; //binary string containing PNG image
$file = fopen('image.tmp', 'wb');
fputs($file, $image);
fclose($file);
$image = new Imagick('PNG:image.tmp');
$image->thumbnailImage($width, $height);
$image->setImageFormat('jpg');
$image->setCompressionQuality(97);
$image->writeImage('image.jpg');
```

The above doesn't work and gives me a black image for [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/thumb/5/50/Adidas_klassisches_logo.svg/220px-Adidas_klassisches_logo.svg.png) image. When doing instead

```
[...]
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->setCompressionQuality(97);
$image->writeImage('image.png');
```

all is fine again. I think it has to do something with transparent background, which isn't available in JPG format. Can anyone help to solve this (imagick isn't documented very well, so I don't know how to help myself).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
$white=new Imagick();
$white->newImage($width, $height, "white");
$white->compositeimage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0);
$white->setImageFormat('jpg');
$white->writeImage('image.jpg');
```

Comment: This is very useful when dealing with PDF's as well, since the `flattenImages` method resets the page to the last one... Thanks @rabudde!

Answer (score 11):

Another way to convert transparent png to jpg, as mentioned in [Imagick::flattenImages](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.flattenimages.php#101164):

```
$im = new Imagick('image.png');
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');

$im->flattenImages(); // This does not do anything.
$im = $im->flattenImages(); // Use this instead.

$im->setImageFormat('jpg');
$im->writeImage('image.jpg');
```

As time moves on,  `flattenImages()` has been deprecated.
Instead of the line above use:

```
$im->mergeImageLayers(Imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN);
```

Comment: flattenImages deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`setBackgroundColor`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setbackgroundcolor.php) to set the default background color to something else than black. The PNG transparency will be replaced by the background color when saving to JPG.

**Edit**: Use it like so:

```
$img->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('#FFFFFF'));
```

Comment: You need to pass an ImagickPixel object, not a color string if you have Imagick <= 2.1. See my edited response.

Comment: I've added `setBackgroundColor` just after calling `new Imagick()`. But that doesn't seem to have any effect. I'm using PHP 5.3.6, ImageMagick 6.7.0, Imagick 3.1.0.

Comment: Calling `exec("convert png.png -resize 500x400 -background white -flatten png_small.jpg")` works perfectly, but why not in PHP with `$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('#FFFFFF'));$image->flattenImages();`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [`$image->setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFF);`](http://lv.php.net/imagick-setbackgroundcolor) after `$image = new Imagick('PNG:image.tmp');`

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Invalid parameter provided'`, using '#ffffff' instead doesn't result in a failure but doesn't help also. `setImageBackgroundColor` doesn't work too