# imagick convert png to jpg in java with im4java

Tags: java, imagick, im4java

I need to convert from PNG to JPG.

However, iMagick adds a black background to it.

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610739/php-imagick-convert-png-to-jpg) which is for PHP, and tried to write the same for java like this:

```
// create the a jpg image
ConvertCmd cmd = new ConvertCmd();
// create the operation, add images and operators/options
IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
op.addImage(brandingURL);
op.format("JPEG");
op.composite();
op.background("white");
op.addImage(imageLocation);
//op.transparent();
// execute the operation
cmd.run(op);
```

But still, the image comes out with a black background.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just a guess: the conversion already replaces the transparent background of the PNG to black before setting the background to white. I assume the white background is then just overwritten with the black background. Maybe you should not convert the image but draw the PNG onto a white JPEG of the same size.

Comment: I'm no ImageMagick expert (you might want to refer to its documentation - it might be the `draw` command) but with plain Java image io you'd create a `BufferedImage` and use the associated `Graphics` object to fill the background and draw the PNG on it.

Comment: It's not going to help me. since the resolution will be low

Comment: Have you tried to use `javax.imageio.ImageIO` instead?

Comment: Of course I tried, but the quality of the image is so poor that I need to use external libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to write the code like this:

```
 Info imageInfo = new Info(brandingURL, true);
 IMOperation op = new IMOperation();
 op.addImage(brandingURL);
 op.size(imageInfo.getImageWidth(), imageInfo.getImageHeight());
 op.addImage("xc:white", "c://write//test.jpeg");
 op.addImage("c://write//test.jpeg");
 CompositeCmd composite = new CompositeCmd();
 composite.run(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `background` should not be necessary.  Accroding to the [documentation](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=2tq973nkgi1iqdi5a65kmjfv32), the default background is white, which suugests to me that maybe one of your pictures has a black background that overwrites/blocks the default (maybe the the one at `brandingURL`?).

Quote from the above linked documentation for ImageMagick:

> -background color
>
> Set the background color.
>
> The color is specified using the format described under the -fill option. The default background color (if none is specified or found in the image) is white.

If you are using it precisely because one of the images *does* specify a (black) background, I suggest you move the `background` call to either before adding that picture or to the end of the operation (Not sure how ImageMagick operates wrt to this)

Comment: I am sure that it doesn't have the black background somewhere