# Converting transparent PDF files with Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

I have a problem creating thumbnails with PHP and imagick. The code is working ok and the thumbnail is generated in the correct size etc but when I try to place a PDF logo on the thumbnail it turns half transparent. I guess it has something to do with the PDF file being generated in InDesign and it probably doesn't have any background defined. Has anyone come across this  problem or has an idea what to do about it? I tried to put a white canvas in the background but that didn't help. I also specified a channel for the compositeImage function but that didn't help either.

This is the PDF file I'm having issues with: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13712643/Case_Study.pdf
The generated Thumbnail looks like this:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13712643/Case_Study1.jpg

The code I have produced so far: http:// pastebin.com/74CYC972

Any ideas? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with my PDF thumbnail feature! Its a pain, and setting the background to transparent doesn't fix it. If I render the image without resizing though the transparency problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by using [Imagick::compositeImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php) that was found in here: [php imagick convert PNG to jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610739/php-imagick-convert-png-to-jpg)

The code goes something like this:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readimage($pdfFile."[$currentPage]");
$res = $im->getimageresolution();

$bg = new Imagick();
$bg->setresolution($res["x"],$res["y"]); //setting the same image resolution

//create a white background image with the same width and height
$bg->newimage($im->getimagewidth(), $im->getimageheight(), 'white');
$bg->compositeimage($im, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0); //merging both images
$bg->setimageformat("png");

//then you can write to a file
$bg->writeImage('white-background-pdf-image.png');

//or output it
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $bg;
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this what you are looking for :

```
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setbackgroundcolor.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

None of the existing answers worked for me. Flatten the image just after creating a new imagick() worked instead:

```
$im = $im->flattenImages();
```

Edit: The flattenImages method has been deprecated & removed. Use

```
$im = $im->mergeImageLayers( imagick::LAYERMETHOD_FLATTEN );
```