# Overlay PNG on JPG using Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have the last few hours tried to get a PNG logo with a transparent background on top of a JPG background. I have tried several ways and with several globals as well, but I do not seem to be able to get the result I want.

**"First Attempt":**

```
$overlay = new Imagick('overlay.png');
$image = new Imagick('background.jpg');

$image->compositeImage($overlay, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 10, 10);
$image->writeImage('background.jpg'); //replace original background

$overlay->destroy();
$image->destroy();
```

[image]

As you can see, the Jaguar logo is all black.

---

**"Second Attempt"**

```
$overlay = new Imagick('overlay.png');
$image = new Imagick('background.jpg');

$image->setImageColorspace($overlay->getImageColorspace() ); 
$image->compositeImage($overlay, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 10, 10);
$image->writeImage('background.jpg'); //replace original background

$overlay->destroy();
$image->destroy();
```

[image]

This one the Jaguar logo looks like it should, but the background is all messed up now.

---

I have tried with [Imagick::setImageMatte](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagematte.php) and tried to add the [overlay to a white background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610739/php-imagick-convert-png-to-jpg#answer-6617001) (thought I does need to have a transparent background) and still it won't display the image properly. I have tried many other variations of the 2 above snippets but they all seem to make the PNG completely or partial black.

What am I missing or doing wrong? Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?
Please note this needs to be done in PHP.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am a huge idiot! Turns out I forgot to convert the images from CMYK to RGB.
For anyone who might encounter this in the future, learn from my incompetence!

Comment: how to convert from CMYK to RGB? can you paste the code?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to overlay a png with transparency over the top of another png. I used this line from [the PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php).

```
$src1->compositeImage($src2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_MATHEMATICS, 0, 0);
```

but I was getting the same problem.  The overlay came through as black only.  Changing it to this seemed to fix the colours.

```
$src1->compositeImage($src2, Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
```