# PHP imagick gif to jpg - background

Tags: php, jpeg, gif, imagick, alpha-transparency

I've this gif:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/2.gif
```

(transparent background)

And with this code:

```
$im = new Imagick();    
$im->readimage("example.gif");     
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(11);    
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');    
$im->setImageFormat("jpg");    
$im->stripImage();    
$im->writeImage("example.jpg");    
$im->clear();    
$im->destroy();
```

Results:

```
https*://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/3.jpg(without *)
```

(gold background)

But want this:

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/76885657/stackoverflow/2.jpg
```

(white background)

Comment: What's in your `$save_as` var? Also, why `$im2`?

Comment: $save_as = "example.jpg";

Comment: Sorry, is $im not $im2

Comment: Ok, just to clarify... You want to rename your rendered jpg as `2.jpg`, is that?

Comment: No, I want to rendered gif as jpg. But with white backroung

Comment: Try only `$im->setBackgroundColor('white')`

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610739/php-imagick-convert-png-to-jpg

Comment: Trying only $im->setBackgroundColor('white') results the same, The link is for png... in gif doesn't work. With $im->setImageAlphaChannel(11); only, returns black

Comment: What about the `flattenImages()`?

Comment: same result. Thanks! i've found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it. Was the order!:

```
$im = new Imagick();    
$im->readimage("example.gif");
```

// Wrong

```
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');  
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(11);
```

// Write!!!

```
$im->setImageAlphaChannel(11);    
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
```

// Rest of code...

```
$im->setImageFormat("jpg");    
$im->stripImage();    
$im->writeImage("example.jpg");    
$im->clear();    
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: Could you explain why you used `11` instead of [Imagick constants](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.constants.php#imagick.constants.alphachannel)? And especially, what does 11 mean?

Comment: I used 11 instead of constants because is a channel, not a color. 11 is the number of channel to change.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... there are constants like `Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_SET`.

Comment: Actually I believe 11 is the value of `Imagick::ALPHACHANNEL_REMOVE`, see: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.flattenimages.php#116956

Comment: You are right, maybe 11 is the number of the constant used in the imagick class to reduce the class code. I don't really know